# get function return value with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get the result of my function convert and display it on the page

Here is my function:

```
$scope.convert = function(myUnit, myUnit2, distance){
    var result = 0;
    if(myUnit === "Kilometer"){
        if(myUnit2 === "Kilometer"){
            result = distance;
        }
        else if(myUnit2 === "Meter"){
            result = distance * 1000;
        }
        else if(myUnit2 === "Centimeter"){
            result = distance * 100000;
        }
        else if(myUnit2 === "Millimeter"){
            result = distance * 1000000;
        }
        else if(myUnit2 === "Mile"){
            result  = distance * 0.621371;
        }
        else if(myUnit2 === "Nautical Mile"){
            result = distance * 0.539957;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the function is called:

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert(myUnit.thisunit, myUnit2.thisunit2, formData.distance)">
     Convert
</button>
```

Here is where I want to display the result:

```
<label class="item item-input" style="border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;">
     <span class="input-label">Result:</span>
     <p>DISPLAY RESULT HERE</p>
</label>
```

I am having a hard time displaying the result... The convert function is inside my controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope)
```

And the button and the place I want to put the value are within scope of my controller. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `result` to a scope property, eg

```
$scope.result = result;
```

and display it in your template

```
<p>{{ result }}</p>
```

---

While I'm here, let me introduce you to the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement

```
var result = 0;
if(myUnit === "Kilometer"){
    switch (myUnit2) {
        case 'Kilometer' :
            result = distance;
            break;
        case 'Meter' :
            result = distance * 1000;
            break;
        // you get the idea
    }
}
$scope.result = result;
```